i am deploying my Django app on vercel but then after deployment is successful i get a 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND when i open the link
I am deploying my Django app on Vercel but then after deployment is successful I get a 404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND when I open the link.
I'm deploying to Vercel. I expected my app to run but is not. i don't know the cause of this error. can anyone help me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This is my vercel.json file {
"version": 2,
"builds": [
{
"src": "Sport/wsgi.py",
"use": "@vercel/python",
"config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
},
{
"src": "build_files.sh",
"use": "@vercel/static-build",
"config": {
"distDir": "staticfiles_build"
}
}
],
"routes": [
{
"src": "/static/(.)",
"dest": "/static/$1"
},
{
"src": "/(.)",
"dest": "Sport/wsgi.py"
}
]
}
